# Make the hover stay on the element that appears from it

Tags: html, css

I have a list such that each list item contains a title. When the title is hovered upon, an info box appears (like the example below).

The problem is that when the cursor is moved from the title to the box, the box disappears.

The requirement is that the box should stay visible when the cursor is moved from the title to the box.

How can this be achieved ?

```css
ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}

ul li + .box {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
    
ul li:hover + .box {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="pt pt1 active" data-cont="r1">
      <p>إصدار رخصة استثمار للمستثمر الأجنبي</p>
  </li>
  <div class="box">
      <div class="steps">
          <div>
              <p>تضاف قيمة 10,000ر.س للاشتراك في خدمات مراكز علاقات المستثمرين بوزارة الاستثمار في السنة الأولى و 60,000 ر.س في السنوات التالية / سنة </p>
          </div>
          <div>
              <p>هذا الإجراء يتطلب إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
          </div>

          <div>
              <p>هذا الإجراء مؤتمت</p>
          </div>
          <div>
              <p>هذا الإجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution requires changes in the nesting structure.

1. Embed the `box` in `li`
2. Keep the list item visible and the embedded box hidden
3. When `li` is hovered upon, make the embedded box `visible`

```css
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:hover > .box {
opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.box {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="pt pt1 active" data-cont="r1">
      <p>إصدار رخصة استثمار للمستثمر الأجنبي</p>
      <div class="box">
          <div class="steps">
              <div>
                  <p>تضاف قيمة 10,000ر.س للاشتراك في خدمات مراكز علاقات المستثمرين بوزارة الاستثمار في السنة الأولى و 60,000 ر.س في السنوات التالية / سنة </p>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <p>هذا الإجراء يتطلب إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
              </div>

              <div>
                  <p>هذا الإجراء مؤتمت</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <p>هذا الإجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will fix your issue.

```css
ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}
ul li .box {
opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    }
    
ul li:hover .box {
opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.box {
background-color: #ccc;
padding: 10px;
text-align: right;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
                            <li class="pt pt1 active" data-cont="r1">
                                <p>إصدار رخصة استثمار للمستثمر الأجنبي</p>
                                <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>تضاف قيمة 10,000ر.س للاشتراك في خدمات مراكز علاقات المستثمرين بوزارة الاستثمار في السنة الأولى و 60,000 ر.س في السنوات التالية / سنة </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>هذا الإجراء يتطلب إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <p>هذا الإجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>هذا الإجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </li>
                            
                  </ul>
```